# How to use vmr7 in renderless mode?

Tags: c#, video, directshow, renderer

When I want to create a vmr7 filter in renderless mode,I find that I can't find this interface IVMRSurfaceAllocatorNotify,it seems the interface has been tagged obsolete.So how can I use the renderless mode and make a custom allocator so that I can render the video in a custom usercontrol?

Answer (score 0):

The interface `IVMRSurfaceAllocatorNotify` is defined in [DirectShow.NET's](https://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/) src\VmRender.cs. The library also provides you with a sample for VMR-9 in Samples\VMR9\VMR9Allocator (and Samples\VMR9\VMR9Allocator2). You can implement renderless VMR-7 in a similar way (VMR-7's interface is actually somewhat simpler).

If you are looking for samples code on how to deal with `IVMRSurfaceAllocatorNotify`, DirectX SDK Extras February 2005 include Renderless and TxtPlayer samples which feature use of VMR-7 renderless mode (C++ code you would need to convert to C#, DirectShow.NET's does have the necessary declarations for `IVMRSurfaceAllocatorNotify`).

Comment: The fact is there is only vmr9 in the samples about renderless mode, but I can’t use the IVMRSurfaceAllocatorNotify interface， so I can't do the same to vmr7.

Comment: "These interfaces are in the source code, but are deprecated, undocumented, 
intended for Ole Automation or otherwise untestable which means they are not, 
and will not be tested:                                    
IVMRSurfaceAllocatorNotify  ……" so，in vs，when i use IVMRSurfaceAllocatorNotify，it tell me it can't find such interface.

Comment: I don't see how this sentence is preventing from using `IVMRSurfaceAllocatorNotify`. This interface, in particular, is not deprecated, [is documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390507). Testable or not, it is usable and is in good standing. It is defined in DirectShow.NET's [src\VmRender.cs](https://github.com/pauldotknopf/DirectShow.NET/blob/master/src/VmRender.cs#L379), so you clearly can take advantage of it. Note "#if ALLOW_UNTESTED_INTERFACES" line in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

On C++ DirectShow code You can use [CLSID_VideoMixingRenderer9](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/dd407344(v=vs.85).aspx) for VMR9 or [CLSID_VideoMixingRenderer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/dd407343(v=vs.85).aspx) for VMR7

`IBaseFilter     *m_pVideoRenderer;
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VideoMixingRenderer9, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, reinterpret_cast<void**> &m_pVideoRenderer));`